# How do you prove that $a + 1 = b$ in a field with 4 elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have a Field with 4 distinct elements {$0, 1, a, b$}. And because $a \cdot b \neq a$, and vice versa, I have filled the $\cdot$ table as:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        \mathbf\cdot & \mathbf0 & \mathbf1 & \mathbf{a} & \mathbf{b} \\
        \mathbf0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \mathbf1 & 0 & 1 & a & b \\
        \mathbf{a} & 0 & a & b & 1\\
        \mathbf{b} & 0 & b & 1 & a\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Now to fill the $+$ table, I can't figure out how to prove by contradiction that $a + 1 = b$, and similarly, $b + 1 = a$.

Any pointers on how to proceed?

EDIT: I'm thinking that the distributive law fits in here somewhere?

Comment: Do you have to prove it by contradiction? What part of the addition table HAVE you filled in? (First row and column don't count...)

Comment: @JohnHughes Yep, I _have to_ prove it by contradiction. I've filled (other than the first row and column) $a + a = 0$ and $b + b = 0$

Comment: BTW: the field is, under +, an abelian group. What can you say about the order of the elements of this group?

Comment: Did you mean to write $a + a  = 0$ rather than $a \cdot a = 0$?

Comment: @JohnHughes Yep, typo :/ What exactly do you mean by order of elements? Sorry, but I'm kind of new to ring theory

Comment: The order is an idea from group theory: it's the smallest $n$ with $a^n = e$ (or, for an abelian group, the smallest $n$ with $a + \ldots + a (\text{$n$ times}) = 0$.

Comment: @JohnHughes ah okay, thanks!

Comment: There is only one way to have a four element field

Comment: Yes, and that's what OP is trying to prove by elementary means, straight from the defining axioms (and apparently by using contradiction for some reason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a+1=a$, then we have $1=0$, impossible.

If $a+1=1$, then we have $a=0$, impossible.

If $a+1=0$, we multiply by $a$ on both sides, getting $a^2+a=0$ or $b+a=0$.  So $b=1$, impossible.

Comment: Oh, okay. So it's basically just trying out the possibilities, right? Does this count as proof by contradiction?

Comment: Yes; if you assume $a+1$ is not $b$, then we get a contradiction (three cases).

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at this problem is to use linear algebra.  Let $F$ be the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $F$ can be identified with a subfield of the field $K$ with four elements.  Then $K$ is a vector space over $F$, where vector addition is the usual addition in $K$, and scalar multiplication is the restriction of the usual multiplication in $K$ to only allow the scalars to be in $F$.

A vector space over a field $F$ (or any field) is isomorphic to a direct sum

$$\bigoplus\limits_{i \in X} F$$

for some indexing set $X$.  Since $K$ has four elements, it must be isomorphic as vector spaces, and in particular as abelian groups, to

$$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$

Now the three nonzero elements $a, b,1$ of $K$ correspond in some order to the elements $(1,0);(0,1);(1,1)$.  Your conclusion follows from the observation that if you add any two of these elements together, you get the third.

Comment: I would say that this is too deep for the OP's background

Comment: @H.Potter It is, but looks quite interesting. I'm actually gonna look those up and follow. I'm gonna have to do this soon enough anyway :)